# How do you deal with multiple PostgreSQL schemas and DBIx::Class?

Tags: perl, postgresql, dbix-class

In my database I have 5 separate schemas so that I can organize objects into logical groups. I used `dbicdump` to create my DBIx::Class schema, but noticed that it only loaded tables from the public schema. I figured out how to load all my schemas using dbicdump, but now I'm at a loss on where to go from here setting everything up and using it. I've looked online for any resources, and found very little documentation. [The only thing I did find](http://blogs.perl.org/users/kaare/2010/10/dbix-class-and-database-schemas-in-postgresql.html), I really wasn't too happy with the solution. I am wondering if anyone has encountered this before, and how they dealt with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need a recent DBIx::Class I believe, but I use something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use v5.14;

use DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader qw/ make_schema_at /;
use Path::Tiny;

my $dest_dir = '.';
my $pkg_base = 'Foo';
(my $pkg_dir = $pkg_base) =~ s/::/\//g;

# Delete any previous run
path($dest_dir.'/'.$pkg_base)->remove_tree;

make_schema_at(
    $pkg_base.'::Schema',
    {
        debug          => 0,
        dump_directory => $dest_dir,
        db_schema      => '%',
        moniker_parts  => ['schema', 'name'],
        #rescan         => 1,
    },
    [ 'dbi:Pg:dbname=mydb port=5432', 'dbuser', 'dbpass' ],
);

exit;
```

That gives me something like:

```
Foo::Schema::Result::PublicTable1
Foo::Schema::Result::Schema2Table2
etc
```

There are details of the various options in the [docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader). I seem to remember I cross-referenced the docs with the source of dbicdump when I put it together.

HTH

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I found that what moniker_parts does is basically takes the parts and joins them, in this case schema (the name of the schema) and name (the name of the table). Therefore, I ended up with GeneralUser.pm (general schema, user table). This is exactly what I was looking for, I wish it was easier to find the documentation on this!

Comment: Yes, it took me a while. I'm not sure it *was* documented in older versions of DBIx::Class.

Comment: `Cclite2OmRegistry` for the table om_registry in schema `cclite2` gives
[2021-04-13 13:12:45.49656] [9448] [error] Cclitedb628 get where error `$VAR1 = bless( {
                 'msg' => 'DBIx::Class::Storage::DBI::_dbh_execute(): DBI Exception: DBD::Pg::st execute failed: ERROR:  relation "om_registry" does not exist
LINE 1: ... me.tags, me.nodetypes, me.feed, me.networks FROM om_registr...` should be cclite2.om_registry. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found this, and it was nearly what I needed. But I wanted traditional :: and separation of true classes (based on tables) with view classes that contain random bits of sql so, I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader qw/ make_schema_at /;
use Path::Tiny;

my $dest_dir = '../sql' ;
my $pkg_base = 'Cclite2';

# Delete any previous run
path($dest_dir.'/'.$pkg_base)->remove_tree;

make_schema_at(
    $pkg_base.'::Schema',
    {
        debug          => 0,
        dump_directory => $dest_dir,
        db_schema      => 'cclite2',
        moniker_parts  => ['schema', 'name'],
        moniker_part_separator => '::',
         naming         => {
            relationships    => 'v8',
            monikers         => 'v8',
            column_accessors => 'v8',
            force_ascii      => 1,

        },

    },

    [ 'dbi:Pg:dbname=dbname', 'dbuser', 'dbpass' ],
);

exit;
```

This gives this:

```
 ├── Schema
│   │   └── Result
│   │       ├── Cclite2
│   │       │   ├── OmAuth.pm
│   │       │   ├── OmCategory.pm
etc.
│   │       │   └── OmYellowpage.pm
│   │       ├── OmAdminBalanceView.pm
│   │       ├── OmAdsRss.pm
etc.
│   │       ├── OmTradesByUserView.pm
│   │       └── OmVolumeView.pm
│   └── Schema.pm
```

This is not criticism of the first answer. It's just an alternative that suits me and may suit others.

Answer (score 0):

You must provide options like below to **make_schema_at** for database schemas to be set up properly:

```
# list the schemas you want to include (also works with 'public' etc.)
db_schema => ['schema1', 'schema2',...],
# make queries work, by using schema.table instead of only table name
qualify_objects => 1,
# set up proper namespacing for result classes
moniker_parts => ['schema', 'name'],
moniker_part_separator => '::',
```

Sources:

1. [db_schema](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader::Base#db_schema)
2. [qualify_objects](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader::Base#qualify_objects)
3. [use DBIx::Class across PostgreSQL/DB2/Oracle schemas](https://metacpan.org/dist/DBIx-Class/view/lib/DBIx/Class/Manual/FAQ.pod#..-use-DBIx::Class-across-PostgreSQL/DB2/Oracle-schemas?)
4. [moniker_parts](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader::Base#moniker_parts)
5. [moniker_part_separator](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader::Base#moniker_part_separator)